# How to update tables to match updated gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [active-record-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/) gem, and would like to update it to `v 2.0.0`.

The gem creates three tables, `RS_Evaluations`, `RS_Reputation_Messages`, and `RS_Reputations`. These three tables have been renamed for v 2.0.0, but they do not get updated in my database by simply bundle installing the v2.0.0 gem.

How can I go about updating these tables? Should I:

**1) Update just the table names with the content of the columns intact?** (To the best of my knowledge, the column names are unchanged with the update). If so, how can I do this?

**2) Drop the older tables and create new correct tables?** This is not ideal, but won't kill me, as I don't have a huge amount of data in the existing tables. Can I simply delete the older tables via my database viewer (ie. PGAdminIII)? Or do I need to migrate a file that drops the tables?

Input would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
The [migration guide](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Migrate-to-Version-2.0) has a line about

```
Also, you need to update your database data as follow: 
UPDATE rs_reputation_messages SET sender_type = 'ReputationSystem::Evaluation' WHERE sender_type = 'RSEvaluation'
```

How would I go about doing this? I am only familiar with updating the database through migration files. Is this an SQL call made directly to the database?

Comment: Back up the DB and try #1 with `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...` statements. If that doesn't work out and it can't be resolved with some more simple ALTERs, try #2 with a simple `DROP TABLE`. If that doesn't work out, look into doing it by migration.

Comment: Thanks @Craig. 2 amateur questions: 1. How do I backup my DB? Can you point me to a source on how to do that? 2. The suggestions you mention, `ALTER TABLE` and `DROP TABLE`, sound like migrations. (ie. changes to a migration file, which are implemented through `rake db:migrate`. How is this different from "doing it by migration"?

Comment: Hi @mu. Not that I can [find](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Migrate-to-Version-2.0). They have an explanation of what methods have been deprecated, but not details on how to update the models. I don't doubt I may be missing something simple though...

Comment: @umezo OMG if you haven't been making backups already. Read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html . The simplest way to back up the DB is `pg_dumpall`. Automate your backups so from now on you keep a rotating set of copies of your DB, say one a day for 7 days (bare minimum).

Comment: @umezo As for `ALTER TABLE` etc - sure, you can do it as SQL in a migration file, or you can just connect to your DB directly via psql/Pgadmin3/whatever and issue the commands.

Comment: Thanks @Craig. Yeah, I need to read up. Funny thing, all these Rails tutorials don't really cover basics like this. It's implied, but for a non-engineer like me, it's not common knowledge... Appreciate the help